# Select data from two table with join

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have two table named `table_a` and `table_b`.

`table_a` data

```
id     name
1     sahadat
2     kamrul
3     Harish
4     Ilma
5     Martin
6     Ponting
```

`table_b` data

```
id      table_a_id
1       2
2       5
3       1
```

Now I want to select data from `table_a` like this

```
id       data
3        Harish
4        Ilma
6        Ponting
```

how do I write query to get this result.

**what I have tried**

```
select * from `table_a` where `id` NOT IN (select table_a_id from table_b);
```

It works when `table_b` have some data. But when `table_b` is empty then it show error

Answer (score 2):

```
select  * from table_a where id not in (select table_a_id from table_b);
```

Comment: I alrady try this solution before posting question. see my update question

Comment: even thought there is no data it wont throw an error just checked it with local sample tables

Comment: other wise try this by default always 0 will come if no data is there 

select  * from table_a where id not in (select table_a_id from table_b union select 0);

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query.

```
SELECT t1.* FROM table_a AS t1 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
( SELECT * FROM table_b AS t2 WHERE t2.table_a_id = t1.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try it**

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_a t1 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT * FROM table_b t2 WHERE t2.table_a_id = t1.id)");
```